# the photo does not appear in the gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-fileprovider

I try to take and save photo in my app. 
I  wrote in manifest the fileprovider and path for him:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="mypacage.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/path" />
            </provider>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images"  path="images"/>

</paths>
```

In my activity I call Fragment Dialog (cameraOrChoosePhoto Dialog) which have a button, next make intent for opening camera and other actions for create file for photo::

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.dialog_camera:
                Uri uri = generateUriPhoto();
                if(uri!=null) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                                                          Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SubItemDetail.CAMERA_RESULT);
                } else dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.dialog_choose_photo:
                break;
        }
    }

    private Uri generateUriPhoto() {
        file = createNameFile(); 
        uri = null;
        if (file != null) {
                      String aut = getActivity().getPackageName()+".fileprovider";
                       uri = getUriForFile(getActivity(), aut, file);

                      getActivity().grantUriPermission(getActivity().getPackageName(), uri, 
                                                                              Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                                                                                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        return uri;

    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {  //  onActivityResult
        return uri;
    }

    private File createNameFile() {
        directory = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "images");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        String name = "photo_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = File.createTempFile(
                    name,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    directory      /* directory */
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dismiss();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Next on my activity:

.........

```
private Uri uri

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        CameraOrChoosePhotoDialog cameraOrChoosePhotoDialog = (CameraOrChoosePhotoDialog)             getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("camera"); 

        uri = cameraOrChoosePhotoDialog.getUri();// get uri from dialogfargment

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {

                 image.setImageURI(uri);
                addPicToGallery(); //  try  to put photo in gallery

                cameraOrChoosePhotoDialog.dismiss();  // close dialog
            }
        }
    }

    private void addPicToGallery() {

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,uri)); 
        mediaScanIntent.setData(uri));
         sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);


    }
```

but the photo does not appear in the gallery

Comment: i think you need to store the image after successfully captures, you are just scanning the files present in the system. first try to compress and save the bitmap using fileOutputStream then scan(sendBroadcast)

Comment: @Demo Mail . but in AMD in Android Studio I see these created files with the extension .jpg. in Folder .../file/images/

Comment: can you able to open that image?? and can u able to see the valid image??

Comment: Yes, I can. I place it wit URI into my ImageViiew. And I can copy it into my PC.

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/pk_rZXogQOyQG5ZunwoalA.png

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the captured file into the image format such as .jpeg, .png etc. and then store it into the device local storage or SD card.

Comment: but in AMD in Android Studio  I see these created files with the extension .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
private void addPicToGallery() {

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,uri)); 
        mediaScanIntent.setData(uri));
         sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);


    }
```

with

```
private void addPicToGallery() {

            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,uri)); 
            mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file)));
             sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
```

somehow initial uri from FileProvider is different from uri you get from actual file :)